# How can I check if I can set (patch) attributes in Python objects

Tags: python, monkeypatching

Setting arbitrary attributes from outside works for normal classes, but not for internal objects like strings?! How can I check if I'm allowed to set arbitrary attributes?

Comment: In general, by trying. But first - why do you want to, especially in a context where you don't already know if you can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try-except`

```
def canSetAttr(o):
    try:
         name = 'probablynotset'
         flag = hasattr(o, name)
         if flag:
             old = getattr(o, name)
         setattr(o, name, 'x')
         if flag:
             setattr(o, name, old)
         else:
             delattr(o, name)

         return True
     except AttributeError:
         return False
```

Comment: Only, don't use a naked `except` - use `except AttributeError`, otherwise this will swallow all exceptions that happen to occur during its exception, including users hitting ctrl-C or ctrl-Z (on windows).

Comment: The bare except will also swallow the NameError probably introduced by using `true` instead of `True`..